# How to build a user input android app?

Tags: android

I'm searching for video tutorials or books on how to make an android app similar to a diary or journal app.

I can't seem to find (googled!!!) anything apart from very basic tutorials on creating a website like app with an email form only.

Is there anything out there you could direct me to?

Comment: You know tutorials are supposed to basic. If you already know the basic tutorials, it's time to read serious books and articles.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, I can't seem to find it - rather don't know what exactly to search for.

Comment: what were your keywords for google search?

Comment: build user input android app, advanced android app tutorial, build a journal app android .. 

I think the question better worded would be, whats the next step after learning the basics - best book etc

Comment: then, search this site with that corrected question.

Comment: Have you looked at the NotePad sample in your sdk given in your sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one example that is quite similar to what you are looking for, that would be the [Notepad Tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)

By extending and improvising from this tutorial, you could achieve what you need to build an app similiar to a Diary or a Journal.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I think this might be perfect for taking my learning to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up an entire tutorial to build an application is not the sort of learning you will benefit from. Instead you want to learn the basics, and then combine them together to make the application you want.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But the way my mind works, if I can learn about a coding language while working on a project I can remember things better. Its the way I managed to learn basic - intermediate php and mysql. Thanks for your input